# preg_match how to know partial value exist

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Basically my preg_match is working fine. However when only a partial value of the text (not digits) exist, I need to know an attempt was tried to enter the right thing.

Example 1:

```
$text = "2000 FC
2 A
100 FH
1200 ACT FC
";
```

Example 2:

```
$text = "2000 FC
2 A
100 FH
ACT FC
";
```

CODE:

```
preg_match("~(?P<value>\d+(?:.\d+)*?)\h(?P<unit>ACT\sFC)~", $text, $act_fc);
```

Example 1 is showing the correct text "1200 ACT FC". When preg_match is executed 1200 is assigned to value and ACT_FC is assigned to unit in the $act_fc array.

However if there is a case like Example 2 with "ACT FC" only, then $act_fc array is empty.

Without doing another preg_match to check only for "ACT FC", is there a way to return ACT_FC was found?  Maybe "unit" could be forced to populate the array and "value" could be null.

NOTE: I am dealing with matching data between newlines, so that part of the code is important to stay nearly the same.

Comment: There's no reason to use a non-greedy quantifier here: `(?:.\d+)*?`. Don't forget that the dot means any character (except the newline) and not a literal dot. To figure a literal dot you need to escape it: `\.`. If you need to make something optional use the `?` quantifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the value part optional with `(?:...)?`:

```
preg_match("/(?:(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)*?)\h)?(?P<unit>ACT\sFC)/", $text, $act_fc);
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ef4df26cccb00c5ba06882d79e89af9a01c3b75).
And here is [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/bY6eS8/4).

Comment: It's better to use a non-capturing group in this case.

Comment: This works great except sometimes the space is missing.  Like 1200ACT FC

Comment: ahh just figured it out with: (?:\h)*?)

Comment: final answer: preg_match("~(?:(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)*?)(?:\h)*?)?(?P<unit>ACT\sFC)~", $text, $act_fc);  

Curious, does the beginning and ending character matter in regex?  In your example you use a "/" and I have a "~".  Is there a best practice?  Thanks for your answer sevalvietl!!!

Comment: In the [Delimiters Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) you can read that _"A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character."_ . For me it is more natural to use **forward slashes** (`/.../`), and in my opinion they are looking better when you use [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (`/.../g`).